# How to avoid filling up an array each time I run a WP_query?

Tags: wp-query, array, sql, performance

I am making a following user system and need some help for retrieving the users ids a user is following.

At the moment I am using the following SQL query for retrieving the users ids a user is following:

```
$following_users_ids = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT follows_id FROM $table_name_users WHERE user_id = $current_user_id");
```

Now, here comes my main problem. To feed the WP_Query with users ids, I am filling up an array like this:

```
foreach ( $following_users_ids as $following_user_id ) {
    $authors[] = $following_user_id->follows_id;
}
```

If the user is following thounsands of users, filling up the array would take a long time.

My arguments for the WP_Query is as follows:

```
$args = array(
  'author__in'     => $authors,
  'posts_per_page' => 12,
  'paged'          => $paged,
);
```

So I need a faster way to retrieve those users ids and feed the WP_Query with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious first step would be to use `get_col` instead of `get_result`. You will get an array returned straightaway so you could skip your `foreach` and go straight to:

```
$args = array(
  'author__in'     => $following_users_ids,
  'posts_per_page' => 12,
  'paged'          => $paged,
);
```

Behind the scenes, `get_col` [does much what you are doing](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1509) but you are not going through [the more complex `get_results` function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1534) before doing it.

With thousands of users, I am not sure that that particular operation is going to be holdup that you think. That is, I'd suspect that maybe the delay is elsewhere, at least a significant part of the delay.

I'd suggest that:

1. You make sure you table is indexed correctly
2. [And you cache the results](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API)-- possibly cache both the IDs and the
   post results

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That is what I was looking for. However, I would like to clarify something. By using get_col, will I still get a delay when having thousands of users?

Comment: Well, yes. There is _always_ a delay when you do anything, but whether the delay is noticable depends on the server and the load on the server.  I would expect more delay when you run the post query actually.